# EJBQL date comparison

Tags: java, date, ejbql

In EJBQL how can compare two date values; suppose

"Select e from Employee e where e.start_date > :start_date"
If I set query parameter with setParameter("start_date", new Date());

An Exception occurs on running..

I wait for your suggestions

Comment: This isn't a mystery crossword.... what exception do you get?

Comment: It could also be interesting to see the class that embodies the `Employee` entity.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found solution sorry for bothering;

Rather I needed to use setParameter("start_date", new Date(), TemporalType.DATE)